# Dynamically mock dependencies with Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a method that logs a message via one function in a node environment and via a different function in a browser environment. To check whether I am in a node or browser environment I use the libraries `detect-node` and `is-browser` like so:

```
const isNode = require('detect-node');
const isBrowser = require('is-browser');

log(level, message, data) {
    if (isNode) {
        this.nodeTransport.log(level, this.name, message, data);
    }
    if (isBrowser) {
        this.browserTransport.log(level, this.name, message, data);
    }
}
```

The variables `isNode` and `isBrowser` are set to true and false (automatically via the package) depending on, well, if I'm in a browser or in a node env.

Now I want to test this behavior using `jest` so I need to mock these npm packages. This is what I tried:

```
function setup() {
    const loggerName = 'Test Logger';
    const logger = new Logger(loggerName);
    logger.nodeTransport = { log: jest.fn() };
    logger.browserTransport = { log: jest.fn() };
    logger.splunkTransport = { log: jest.fn() };
    return { logger, loggerName };
}

test('it should call the the appropriate transports in a node environment', () => {
    const { logger } = setup();
    const message = 'message';
    jest.mock('detect-node', () => true);
    jest.mock('is-browser', () => false);
    logger.log('error', message, []);
    expect(logger.nodeTransport.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(logger.browserTransport.log).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test('it should call the the appropriate transports in a browser environment', () => {
    const { logger } = setup();
    const message = 'message';
    jest.mock('detect-node', () => false);
    jest.mock('is-browser', () => true);
    logger.log('error', message, []);
    expect(logger.nodeTransport.log).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(logger.browserTransport.log).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

You see, I am using `jest.mock` to mock `detect-node` and `is-browser` and give it different return values. However, this just does not work. The first test is green because (I assume) Jest runs in node, but the second test fails saying

> Expected mock function not to be called but it was called with:
>   ["error", "Test Logger", "message", []]

Answer (score -1):

Use [.mockClear()](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockclear) to reset the mock calls between tests.

```
afterEach(() => {
    logger.nodeTransport.log.mockClear();
    logger.browserTransport.log.mockClear();
});
```